# Why can't I award a bounty of less than 200 on this question?

Tags: support, bounty

I put a bounty of 100 on the question [Has any national leader ever climbed as far as fast as Ulysses S Grant?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41302/has-any-national-leader-ever-climbed-as-far-as-fast-as-ulysses-s-grant/42398#42398). I wanted to split it between two answers but it's not possible (I guess I should have checked that...duh). Anyway, I decided to give the 100 to one of the answers I like and then start another bounty to award the other answer I like.

Problem is, when I tried to start another bounty, it wouldn't let me do less than 200 (I want to give 100, same as the other answer I awarded). I don't get it. I've given 50 elsewhere a few times now so why can't I give less than 200? I just want to give the Napoleon answer 50 or 100, not 200.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained on the page [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) in our Help Centre:

> ... if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

The first bounty you offered was 100 rep, so the minimum spend for a second bounty will be double that, or 200 rep, as you discovered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, my fault because I didn't research this properly but I don't get this rule.

Comment: @FruitMonster  I believe it is to avoid situations like this:  Imagine that you post an answer to a question.  You then put a bounty on that question.  Because of the bounty, the question gets more views, and the chances are that your answer also gets upvoted more (simply because more people saw it).  If your answer gets more than 5 votes from visitors that only saw it because the question had a bounty, then you've gained extra rep even allowing for the cost of the bounty.  Doubling the cost means you're less likely to be able to do this more than once.

Comment: Thank you again. I can see what you mean.